# Wordpress- Creating an archive template

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a custom  archive template for my categories. I have a `parent category` called
`member-resources`, which is a parent category for `multiple other categories`.

I do not want to access these categories by `/category/member-resources`.
According to wordpress documentation for template hierarchy, I need to create `archive-member-resources.php` and change the php code to display as needed.

However this template is not the one being rendered(archive.php is always being rendered), and if I try to access it by entering `/member-resources` I get a 404..

What am I missing ? thanks

**[EDIT]**

Excuse my wordpress skills as  I have only been working with it for about a month..

I asked this question for a very simple reason. I worked on a project, in which I ended up with a massive `archive.php`  file with alot of `conditional logic` such as :

- `if( is_category('events') )`, render a side menu
- `if( is_category('news') )` ,  render something else
- `if( is_category('member-resources') )` render pagination

  This is just an example, but I wanted to highlight that with different categories, I might want to call a completely different archive template( if at all possible ), rather than having a large file which is not very maintainable..

If this cannot be done, please provide me with a solution, so that on my next project, I wouldn't run into this problem again.

Comment: I think you are talking about custom taxonomy, not category

Comment: Sorry, no what I mean is that I have a category called 'member-resources'.. forget the custom. sorry for that.. And I want to create a custom archive template whcih is rendered for the member-resources category and its children. Also this category is used for `attachment` post types only

Comment: ok can you tell me that are you create a custom post type and taxonomy or you use wordpress post and their category....please let me know about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use any type of archive page (archive.php, category.php, taxonomy.php etc) as a listings/index page. That is not what archive pages are intended for. Also, the template hierarchy specific to archive-xxx.php is for custom post types, not categories.

The main query on any archive page is quite specific and should not be tampered with on template level. It totally destroys pagination and common logic within the main query.

You should make use of a page template. Just simply copy your page.php, rename it to page-xxx.php, add the necessary page header and modify it as needed

For further reading

- [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)
- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. How can I use a page template to render it instead of an archive ? Thanks

Comment: I edited my question, which might be more clear to you what I am asking. I appreciate all the help I can get. thanks and rgrds

Comment: Why are you using an archive template for this? The only archive page that is going to work the way you want it to with your naming convention is category.php where you can name it category-categoryslug.php. See [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)